# Multipage typescript project

Tags: typescript

I'm looking into setting up a large Typescript project where instead of compiling all javascript files to a single bundle.js there is a bundled (with all dependencies included) js compiled for each individual page.

**Example project structure:**

```
ts/common/utils.ts
ts/components/datepicker.ts
ts/modules/products.ts
ts/modules/products/productlist.ts
ts/modules/products/editproduct.ts
ts/modules/groups.ts
ts/modules/groups/grouplist.ts
ts/modules/groups/editgroup.ts
```

The above example has 2 pages

- products with bundled js: products.js
- groups with bundled js: groups.js

`products.js` consists of

- utils.ts
- datepicker.ts
- products.ts
- productlist.ts
- editproduct.ts

All the required imports start at `products.ts`. So one could just compile `products.ts` and Typescript should resolve all necessary dependencies.

I'm new to Typescrypt and I've been looking at a Typescript only solution, but that seemed to require tsconfig.json per page and including components from a parent directory wouldn't work.

Preferrably I would like to automatically compile `/modules/xxxxx.ts` to `/public/js/xxxxx.js` with all imports included.

What would be the best approach to setup a project like this?

Comment: You can use Webpack !! to combine modules

Comment: any tips for a particular approach to webpack? I've looked into webpack but couldn't find dynamic multibundle naming. Eg source file was `products.ts` so target should be `products.js`

Comment: Webpack basically combines all different modules into one javascript, it will also bring back code from referenced modules and put it in correct loading sequence. Don't use typescript to combine all sources into one, instead use individual modules.

Comment: Also webpack does this automatically, you just have to give entry point, that is your application javascript, it will load dependencies automatically and it will create bundle file.

Comment: It sounds like you want multiple entry points.  An "entry point" in `webpack` is your top level file.  Take a look at the "multi page application" section on [this piece](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/) of the webpack documentation.  Also, are you using any kind of framework?  `angular-cli` uses webpack internally and Angular "modules" implement exactly this kind of lazy loading for single page applications that don't want to load all the code at once.

Comment: thanks! It seems webpack multi page application is what i'm looking for, although [the example](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/#multi-page-application) shows static naming. Will have to see if names derived from sourcefile also is supported. Further our project doesn't allow us to use Angular or similar framework.

Comment: @FrankDekker webpack is good for single page, multiple entry points are possible but are nightmare on long run as it keeps getting bigger and longer. Try SystemJS,  generate UMD from typescript and use SystemJS to load first page, it will automatically load rest of modules in browser.

Comment: @Akash the conclusion so far has been: components.js (bundle for global components), products.js (bundle for page specific modules), groups.js (bundle for page specific modules). For production this works well, as we can just release packages. I'm running into development problems, that the webpack watcher doesn't recognize changes to the sub modules. If i make changes to the top file, it will recompile. If i make changes to an included module, nothing happens.